# while loop in java (blackjack)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to program a basic game of Blackjack. The problem I am having is I can not get the program to allow input after the first choice within the loop. For example if the player chooses to hit on their first turn, it works, but on their next turn I can not get the program to allow input. here is what i have. any suggestions?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BlackJack {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack");
    int guess = 1+(int)(Math.random()*13);
    int guess2 = 1+(int)(Math.random()*13);
    int answer = guess + guess2;
    System.out.println("Player 1 hand: " + answer);
    System.out.println("Do you want to hit(1) or stay(2)");

    boolean looping = true;
    while(looping){
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        int guess3 = 1+(int)(Math.random()*13);
        int hand = guess3 + answer;
    if(choice == 1){
        if(guess3 == 1){
            System.out.println("Player 1 drew an Ace!");
            System.out.println("Player 1 hand: " + hand);
            System.out.println("Do you want to hit(1) or stay(2)");
        }else if(guess3 > 1 && guess3 <= 10){
            System.out.println("Player 1 drew a"  + guess3 +"!");
            System.out.println("Player 1 hand: " + hand);
            System.out.println("Do you want to hit(1) or stay(2)");
        }else if(guess3 == 11){
            System.out.println("Player 1 drew a Jack!");
            System.out.println("Player 1 hand: " + hand);
            System.out.println("Do you want to hit(1) or stay(2)");
        }else if(guess3 == 12){
            System.out.println("Player 1 drew a Queen");
            System.out.println("Player 1 hand: " + hand);
            System.out.println("Do you want to hit(1) or stay(2)");
        }else if(guess3 == 13){
            System.out.println("Player 1 drew a King!");
            System.out.println("Player 1 hand: " + hand);
            System.out.println("Do you want to hit(1) or stay(2)");
        }
        if(choice == 2){
            looping = false;
        System.out.println("Player 1 has decided to stay");
        }if(hand > 21){
            looping = false;
            System.out.println("You have busted!");
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure your program is breaking the way you think it is. I don't see where `choice` is being changed from within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in every if statement you `break` from the loop and do not enter it again.

What you need is a looping condition which is true until either the player busts or chooses to stay and don't `break` from the loop in every if statement, instead i think you might want to use `continue`

```
boolean looping = true;
while (looping){
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
    //.... edit
    if (choice == 1){
         //Do your card/hand handling code here
    }
    //.... end of edit
    else if(choice == 2 || hand >= 22){
         looping = false;
         continue;  //Alternatively just break;
    }
}
```

Also you could reduce all your if statements to fewer cases as for 2-10 you could just do this

```
if(guess3 > 1 && guess3 <= 10){
    System.out.println("Player 1 drew an "  + guess3 +"!");
    System.out.println("Do you want to hit(1) or stay(2)");
}
```

**EDIT** In response to your comments.

The program will keep adding cards as all your card handling code needs to be in the following condition

```
if (choice == 1){
     //Do your card/hand handling code here
}
```

Currently this is not the case so your program with just add cards every time as you don't check what the user has chosen.

Comment: Thank you!. Everything you have said here has really helped. The only issue I am having now is when the player chooses to stay(2),the program still picks cards until it busts.

Comment: actually even if i choose to hit the program keeps hitting until it busts.

Comment: For every iteration of the loop you need to make sure you get correct input each time and only if they choose to hit get a card. See edit, also read The recommendations made by Mena.

Comment: This is the revised code I have. I added the if(choice==1) before the card code but Im still getting the same problem. This time when I choose to stay nothing is output at all. Edit in original post.

Comment: This is because your code for handling your stay choice is now in your code for hit choice, look at the logic. If choice is 1 it can never be 2 in the same block of code. See my edit to the first block of code in my post.

Comment: ok I see what you mean now. It works perfectly now. Thank you for all the help I have been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: Also you are always getting a card and adding it to the players hand before you check what they have chosen. So it might not yet be correct. You should only add the card if they choose to hit!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are literally taking the user's input only once.

Instead of:

```
int choice = scan.nextInt();
while(choice == 1){
    // etc.
}
```

... you should implement an infinite loop:

```
while (true) {
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
}
```

... Also, you should catch `InputMismatchException`s for unexpected input types, and allow the user to get out of the loop.

Altogether I would recommend:

- using the infinite loop as per above
- using `Scanner#nextLine` instead of `Scanner#nextInt`
- getting a `String` as a result
- checking for something starting with "q" or such like for the user
  wanting to quit
- otherwise, attempting to parse an `Integer` out of the `String` with
  `Integer.parseInt` and catching the eventually resulting
  `NumberFormatException`

Also, I'd strongly recommend using a `switch` statement to categorize the `Integer` from the user, instead of the messy if-then-else.

Comment: I am not familiar with a switch statement. This is my first year taking a programming class. It would be great if you could explain the concept. My teacher does not really explain things and tells us to google it.

Comment: @user2741129 Well. If you google "java switch" you'll find [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) page right on top. Doesn't it explain enough for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the break statements means that your loop performs a very limited function, more like an if. On breaking out of the loop you have no more code to run.

If your loop worked your use of answer and hand variables means that you would never get a correct value (each time around the loop just adding the original two values to the third value). Either store the cards in a list, or keep a cumulative score.

You have a lot of repetition, consider using a switch case  on guess3 where 1 outputs the Ace statement 2 through 10 are all the same (so, no break statements) 'System.out.println("Player 1 drew a " + guess3 + "!");'. This can be followed by the prompt for stick/twist and the reading of the next value.